# Why am I getting the error 'Can't call method "submitted" without a package or object reference' when generating a form in Catalyst?

Tags: perl, catalyst, formbuilder

I'm using the following code to generate a simple form with Catalyst:

```
sub edit : Local {
    my ($self, $c) = @_;
    my $form = $self->formbuilder;
    if ($form->submitted && $form->validate) {
        $c->stash->{message} = 'Thanks for submitting the form!';
    }
}
```

However, when I run it I get this error message:

> Caught exception in AddressBook::Controller::Person->edit "Can't call method "submitted" without a package or object reference at /Users/me/Docs/workspace/MyAddressBook/AddressBook/script/../lib/AddressBook/Controller/Person.pm line 58."

Any ideas on what is causing this?

Answer (score 1):

According to [the fine manual](http://search.cpan.org/~mstrout/Catalyst-Controller-FormBuilder-0.06/lib/Catalyst/Controller/FormBuilder.pm), the attribute `:Form` is part of what triggers the form creation, e.g.:

```
sub edit : Local Form {
    my ( $self, $c, @args ) = @_;
    ...
```

I'd say without that, it's not getting configured, and hence does not have a `submitted` method.

Comment: OMG call me an idiot please.  stupid mistake.  Thank you  for showing me the way.  Added Form and worked like a charm.

Comment: Fresh pair of eyes, that's all :-)